# Change LINQ script if/else query

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to modify a list which looks like this:

```
{"BAY-T", "HBC-T", "AAPL-O", "ABC'D-T", "MAN'D-O", "GBL-LN"}
```

needs to be changed to:

```
{"BAY.TO", "HBC.TO", "AAPL", "ABC.D.TO", "MAN.D", "GBL.L"}
```

Is there a way to do this in LINQ?  Here's what I've got so far:

```
var cleanedupCompList = Companies
.Select (c => new {
    Tick = c.Fc_ticker.Contains("'") ? c.Fc_ticker.Replace("'", ".") : 
        c.Fc_ticker.Contains("-T") ? c.Fc_ticker.Replace("-T", ".TO") :
        c.Fc_ticker.Contains("-O") ? c.Fc_ticker.Replace("-O", "") :
        c.Fc_ticker.Contains("-LN") ? c.Fc_ticker.Replace("-LN", ".L") :
        c.Fc_ticker});
```

However, I'm not getting results that I want.  What do I need to change?

Comment: once one of the conditions is true, the ternary operation will stop, the rest won't be evaluated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to do the `Contains()` checks.  Just do the replacements:

```
c.Fc_ticker.Replace("'", ".").Replace("-T", ".TO")
               .Replace("-O", "").Replace("-LN", ".L")
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't realize how simple this was.  I was over-thinking it.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var Companies = new [] {"BAY-T", "HBC-T", "AAPL-O", "ABC'D-T", "MAN'D-O", "GBL-LN"};
var cleanedupCompList = Companies
      .Select (c => c.Replace("'", ".").Replace("-T", ".TO").Replace("-O", "").Replace("-LN", ".L"));
```